# Multithreaded client-server socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, lwip

I am implementing a Multi-threaded client-server socket programming in C on the same machine with the same IP-Address but with different ports for Client and Server. I have implemented it using pthread concepts in C environment. But I can see only my Client thread is running whereas my server thread has stopped once it reached 'accept()' routine. 
I am wondering what may be the problem. If any one can find out where I am making a mistake then it would be really helpful

My CLIENT code looks like this:

```
void *client_connect(void *arg)
{

   int client_socket;
   struct sockaddr_in Serv_Addr;
   struct sockaddr_in Client_Addr;
   int addrlen=sizeof(Client_Addr);

   char send_buffer_client[] = {"server message"};
   char recv_buffer_client[1024];
   int nbytes;

   client_socket = lwip_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (client_socket < 0) ;

   memset((char *)&Serv_Addr, 0, sizeof(Serv_Addr));
   Serv_Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   Serv_Addr.sin_len = sizeof(Serv_Addr);
   Serv_Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");
   Serv_Addr.sin_port = 9999;
   memset((char *)&Client_Addr, 0, sizeof(Client_Addr));
   Client_Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   Client_Addr.sin_len = sizeof(Client_Addr);
   Client_Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");
   Client_Addr.sin_port = 5555;

   lwip_connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&Serv_Addr, sizeof(Serv_Addr));

   while (1) {

               do{
                   nbytes = lwip_recv(client_socket, recv_buffer_client, sizeof(recv_buffer_client),0);
                   if (nbytes>0) lwip_send(client_socket, send_buffer_client, sizeof(send_buffer_client), 0);

                   printf("server message = %s\n", recv_buffer_client);
               }  while (nbytes>0);

               sleep(10);

       }
       lwip_close(client_socket);
}
```

My SERVER code:

```
void *server_connect(void *arg)
{

   int server_socket;
   struct sockaddr_in Serv_Addr;
   struct sockaddr_in Client_Addr;
   int addrlen=sizeof(Client_Addr);
   int clientfd;
   char send_buffer[] = {"Server message"};
   char recv_buffer[1024];
   int nbytes_server, client_length;

   server_socket = lwip_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (server_socket < 0)
   printf("could not create server socket");
   else
   printf("created SERVER socket");

   memset((char *)&Serv_Addr, 0, sizeof(Serv_Addr));
   Serv_Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   Serv_Addr.sin_len = sizeof(Serv_Addr);
   Serv_Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");
   Serv_Addr.sin_port = 9999;


   client_length = sizeof(Client_Addr);
   if (lwip_bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&Serv_Addr, sizeof(Serv_Addr)) < 0) {           
           printf("could not BIND");
   }

   if ( lwip_listen(server_socket, 20) != 0 ){
            printf("could not BIND");
   }
   while (1) {
                lwip_accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&Client_Addr, &client_length);                

               do{
                nbytes_server = lwip_recv(server_socket, recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer),0);
                if (nbytes_server>0){lwip_send(server_socket, send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer), 0);}

                printf("client message = %s\n", recv_buffer);
                }while(nbytes_server>0); 
                sleepms(10);
       }
       lwip_close(server_socket);
}

void main(void)
{
    pthread_t  client_thread;
    pthread_t  server_thread;

    pthread_create(&server_thread, NULL, server_connect, NULL);
    pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, client_connect, NULL);

    while(1){
        sleepms(1);
        }
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing it the wrong way

Regards
Deb

Comment: you need to try reformatting your code. Also on the client side,  if (client_socket < 0); does not look right.

Comment: First, I'd add "\n" and exit/return after the printf's for failure; the code continues on after errors at the moment. Next, skip creating the threads, and call server_connect directly. Then try connecting via telnet and see if you connect.

Answer (score 2):

Here's atleast 3 errors:

lwip_accept() returns a new socket descriptor, you should use that to read from the client, not read from the original server socket (note also that lwip_accept will block until someone actually connects to the server).

Your port numbers might be off too if you're on a little endian machine, they're normally in network byte order, you should do
`Serv_Addr.sin_port = htons(9999);` and same for the client port - [htons](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/htonl.html) converts the short from host endian to network endian

You're not sending any data ! Your client waits for the server to send it something. But your server doesn't send anything, it waits for the client to send something. Nothing will happen.

Check if lwip_connect fails too, and inspect [errno](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html) if your environment provides it, as it might give clues to what goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same machine, the IP address 1.2.3.4 you're using is not the typical address for localhost, which should be 127.0.0.1.  Unless you have actually made the IP address of the machine using a router or some other means the IP address 1.2.3.4, that address won't resolve, and even though you're trying to run the client and server on the same machine, they won't find each other since there is no way to resolve 1.2.3.4 to a given machine on the network.

Also you don't need to lock the server to a specific IP address, you can just use the constant `INADDR_ANY` from `netinet/in.h` which will bind the socket to any interface on the system.  On the client side though you will still need the correct IP address, but again, if it's the localhost, you can just use 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

(1) It looks as if both client and server are waiting to receive something before echoing it back.  Someone has to talk first.

(2) I don't see where your lwip_accept returns a new socket with which to communicate with the client.  You end up doing recv/send on the listening socket.

(3) Also consider your code here:

```
while (1)
{
    lwip_accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&Client_Addr, &client_length);

    do
    {
        nbytes_server = lwip_recv(server_socket, recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer), 0);

        if (nbytes_server > 0)
        {
            lwip_send(server_socket, send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer), 0);
        }

        printf("client message = %s\n", recv_buffer);
    }
    while (nbytes_server > 0);

    sleepms(10);
}
```

You read and echo a message but never close the socket (probably wise because it is the listening socket!) and immediately loop back to block on accept again.  If client doesn't connect again you will be blocked in that accept forever.

(4)  You don't need those sleepms() calls.  Use pthread_join() in main and just get rid of the rest.  It looks like all your calls block anyway.